# opendir error?

Tags: c++, c, opendir

I get an error with this istruction:

```
  dp = opendir ("%APPDATA%/.");

  output: 
  Couldn't open directory: Mo such file or directory.
```

but I don't get an erro with this istruction:

```
dp = opendir ("C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/.");

output:
.
..
Local
LocalLow
Roaming
```

Why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`opendir` doesn't expand meta variables like `%APPDATA%`, the shell does. So such things work from the command line, but not from a program. In your program, you have to use an absolute or relative path.

You can probably obtain the required path with `getenv()`,

```
const char *appData = getenv("APPDATA");
if (appData) {
    dp = opendir(appData);
} else {
    /* die or recover */
}
```

Comment: I'm no Windows expert, but you'd probably have to use `getenv()` for that. Try `const char* appData = getenv("APPDATA"); dp = opendir(appData);`

Comment: I don't know about C++, in C you could use `getenv` to look up the value of `APPDATA`. Well, at least on *nixish systems, not sure about Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Because the first `opendir` is **LITERALLY** trying to open the directory `%APPDATA%/.`.